# ¿Como validar textBox para que acepte punto, coma, y solo numeros en un textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Hoy dia vengo con un problema que no he podido solucionar, tengo un textbox que solo debe poder insertar numeros, comas, y puntos.

Tengo una validacion pero esta validacion permite insertar signos de admiracion, interrogacion, entre otros.

Estoy haciendo la validacion con el evento KeyPress

```
       if (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (Char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
            toolTip1.Show("Solo se permiten numeros", txtLimite, 3000);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Ejemplo esperado: 1,500.50

Ejemplo de error: 1,500.00!?!?¡¿ entre otros signos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, `IsPunctuation` admite otros signos de puntuación ademas de la coma y el punto.

Deberías comparar directamente el carácter tecleado con estos dos caracteres concretos:

```
if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
    || e.KeyChar == ',' || e.KeyChar == '.')
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
else
{
    toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
    toolTip1.Show("Solo se permiten numeros", txtLimite, 3000);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Cómo puedo hacer para que solo ingrese a sola ves el punto (.)?
Gracias!

Comment: @Luis Deberías hacer una pregunta para que te den soporte.