# Como podria validar que los datos que recibido por un texbox sean numeros, sin utilizar ningun metodo en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, consola

hola buenas tardes comunidad, quisiera hacer una validacion de datos pero no me funciona la validación de la manera que la estoy haciendo pues solo me toma un valor como verdadero, y los demás los lee como distinto. lo que quisiera hacer es recorrer ese estring e ir comprobando que si cada caracter de rut_ es igual al que tengo en mi string numeros pero no me funciona, y no puedo usar ningún método para validar. Es un trabajo para la universidad. les agradecería su ayuda

```
string rut_ = "263285p5-7";
string numeros = "1234567890";
char[] rutDatosNumericos= new char[8];
int longitud= rutDatosNumericos.Length;
int largo= rut_.Length;
string subRut_="0";
Console.WriteLine(largo);
string rutdatos="";
bool validar = false;

for(int i = 0; i <=rutDatosNumericos.Length-1; i++)
{
    rutDatosNumericos[i] = (char)rut_[i];
    Console.WriteLine(rutDatosNumericos[i] + "\n");
}
if(largo<10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Falta un numero");
    subRut_+= rut_;
    Console.WriteLine(subRut_);
    
}
else if (largo == 10)
{
    subRut_ = rut_;
    Console.WriteLine("caracteres completos");
    Console.WriteLine(subRut_);
}
Console.WriteLine("Valor del rut actual: "+ subRut_);


for (int i = 0; i <= rutDatosNumericos.Length-1 ; i++)
{
    
    if (subRut_[i] == numeros[i] +1)
    {
        rutDatosNumericos[i] = (char)subRut_[i];
        Console.WriteLine("Dato guarddo " + rutDatosNumericos[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No es un numero");
    }
}
```

Comment: El código ni siquiera funciona puesto que las variables `subRut_` y `numeros` no existen. Por favor, intentad proporcionar código que al menos sea válido... Porque tal cual está tu pregunta, podría responderte que no funciona porque tienes variables que no existen, e imagino que ese no será el problema real con el que necesitas ayuda. Además, escribir todo en mayúsculas es equivalente a gritar... por favor edita el título y ponlo en minúsculas.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por tus correciones, te agradezco mucho. pude hacer las modificaciones y agregar el codigo que tengo completamente

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como validar textBox para que acepte punto, coma, y solo numeros en un textbox?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132606/como-validar-textbox-para-que-acepte-punto-coma-y-solo-numeros-en-un-textbox) o [Como validar cajas de texto, que solo admita numeros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/188856/169744)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para validar sin usar ningún método puedes usar el índice de la tabla ASCII. Me explico:

Todos los caracteres en la tabla ASCII tienen asignado un número/codigo único, por lo que si intentas comparar si el carácter es menor o mayor que el otro depende en realidad estás comparando los números asignados si son mayores o menores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto, puedes hacer una validación mirando si está dentro del rango:

```
        string rut_ = "263285p5-7"; //entrada
        char inicio = '0';//carcater inicial del rango a buscar
        char final = '9';//caracter final del rango a buscar

        string rutanumerica = ""; //salida
     
     
        for (int i = 0; i <= rut_.Length - 1; i++)//tantas vueltas como caracteres d'entrada
        {

            if (rut_[i] >=inicio && rut_[i]<=final)//comparamos char con char = índice char por índice de char
            {
             rutanumerica+=rut_[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Dato guarddo " + rut_[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No es un numero " + rut_[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Resultado:" + rutanumerica);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Amigo Me sirvió muchisimo el algoritmo era justo lo que necesitaba para terminar mi tarea, Te agradezco mucho por tu ayuda.